# How to get data in Linq to EF join between four tables using count?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, join

I am trying to get data using Linq to Ef I am new to Linq,

I have tables,

```
*region having region_id , region_name
*governorate having governorate_id,governorate_name, region_id
*Student having id,governorate_id
*Teachers having id,governorate_id
```

I want to find count of students and teachers under each region by using one linq to EF query

I try to do it in sql query like only for student,

```
select R.region_id,R.region_name , count(IR.Id) as Individual from region R 
inner join governorate G
           on r.region_id=g.region_id
inner join Student IR
            on g.governorate_id=IR.governorate_id
group by R.region_id,R.region_name
```

Hopes for your suggestions

Comment: Please show the class model including navigation properties. If appropriate navigation properties are in place this should be trivial.

Comment: @ Gert no navigation properties I already checked :)

Comment: Then stop hurting yourself and create them! Really, that's the power of LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using also Ef I'd sugest you to set up the relations between the entities correctly so you dont need to build the join query by youself (and use Include clause).

For example:

```
public class Region
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Governorate> Governorates { get; set; }
}

public class Governorate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public Region Region { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int GovernorateId { get; set; }
    public Governorate Governorate { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it helps you,

Update with a query that may help you:

```
var result = whatever.Regions
            .Include(r => r.Governorates)
            .ThenInclude(g => g.Students)
            .GroupBy(r => new {r.Id, r.Name})
            .Select(g => new
            {
                g.Key.Id,
                g.Key.Name,
                Individual = g.Count(r => r.Id)
            }).ToList();
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To count students and teachers in one query:

```
var teachersStudents =
    (
        from r in db.Region
        join g in db.Governorate on r.region_id equals g.region_id
        join s in db.Student on g.governorate_id equals s.governorate_id
        join t in db.Teacher on g.governorate_id equals t.governorate_id
        group new { r, s, t } by new { r.region_id, r.region_name }
        into grp
        select new
        {
            grp.Key.region_id,
            grp.Key.region_name,
            CountStudents = grp.Select(s => s.s.id).Distinct().Count(),
            CountTeachers = grp.Select(t => t.t.id).Distinct().Count()
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: @setup but I also need to return for Teachers in this linq query

Comment: thanks for your efforts but need to use one Linq query to get count of both students and teacher not separately